# MySQL join query appears to be valid but not performing as expected

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm relatively new to using joins in MySQL.

I have two tables:

```
sh_subscriptions
    => id
    => user_id
    => feed_id

sh_feeds
    => id
    => shop_name
    => feed_id
```

I'm trying to get all fields from `sh_subscriptions` where the `feed_id` corresponds to the `feed_id` in `sh_feed`s that corresponds to `$row['shop_name']` and where `user_id` corresponds to `$id['id]`.

Here's my attempt:

```
SELECT * FROM sh_subscriptions s
INNER JOIN sh_feeds f ON s.shop_id = f.feed_id
WHERE s.id = '" . $id['id'] . "'
AND f.shop_name = '" . $row['shop_name'] . "'
```

**UPDATE**

I now have the following:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    echo "<div class='col-md-4'>";
    echo $row['shop_name'] . " ";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM sh_subscriptions s INNER JOIN sh_feeds f ON s.feed_id = f.feed_id WHERE s.user_id = '" . $id['id'] . "' AND f.shop_name = '" . $row['shop_name'] . "'") or die(mysql_error($con));
    echo "</div>";
}
```

I can confirm that the database fields all exist and that the variables are printing out correctly, but despite having included an error handler, nothing inside the `div` is printed.

Comment: why you use  s.shop_id = f.feed_id instead of  s.feed_id = f.feed_id ?

Comment: "not performing as expected", how? Does `sh_subscriptions.shop_id` exist? You don't show it in list of columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM sh_subscriptions s
INNER JOIN sh_feeds f ON s.id = f.feed_id
WHERE s.id = '" . $id['id'] . "'
AND f.shop_name = '" . $row['shop_name'] . "'") or die(mysql_error($con));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
SELECT * FROM sh_subscriptions s
INNER JOIN sh_feeds f ON s.feed_id = f.feed_id
WHERE s.id = '" . $id['id'] . "'
AND f.shop_name = '" . $row['shop_name'] . "';
```